# Feelings she hardly (recognize, or recognizes)?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I'm confused what verb is correct.

> - Feelings she hardly **recognize**.
> - Feelings she hardly **recognizes**.

Is the verb 'recognize' for 'she' or for 'feelings'?

Comment: I included the examples from the title in the post.  Please see the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 3):

*Feelings*, which are not aware, cognizant beings, can't usually *recognize* anything.  So *she* must be the subject of the verb.

This is a fairly standard use of the [adjective clause](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adjectives/adjective-clause.html), which you should learn to recognize.  The typical form is a noun followed by some phrase modifying the noun. Example:

> The tree **that she used to climb as a child**.

It's not uncommon to drop "that" or other [subordinate conjunctions](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.htm) from adjective phrases:

> The tree (that) she used to climb as a child
>
> The bank teller (who) I spoke with.
>
> The city (which) I grew up in.

And so on.  In this case "(that) she hardly recognizes" modifies "feelings".  As an example:

> Feelings ((that) she hardly recognizes) are rushing over her.

As a side note:  It's unusual to hear this sentence in the present tense, as I would expect it to be part of some narrative.  Narratives commonly use the past tense:

> Feelings she hardly **recognized** were washing over her.